# Best Way to Implement Natural Language Search on a Site

Tags: mysql, search

I implemented a basic search on my site using a like clause in MySQL.  But it doesn't help in many cases.

I have a search I am testing with: "swift bird"
The entry in the database is: "Swift"

What do people usually do in order to catch as many of the possibilities, abbreviations, and variations of the words they need to find when implementing their own basic search on their site?

If you want to test, here is the url for this:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/birds/search_birds.php

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3):

Have you investigated MySQL's Full Text Search capabilities?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html